# Proper alignment of the div

Tags: html

I have the following collection of divs:

```
<div class="header" style="width:960px; height:120px; border:thin; border:1px solid black">
            <div class="logo" style="width:180px; height:100px; border:thin; border:1px solid black; float: left; margin-top:10px; margin-left:10px; margin-bottom:10px">
                LOGO
            </div>
            <div class="fbook" style="float: right; margin-top:50px; margin-right:5px">
                <img src="facebook.png"/>
            </div>
            <div class="signup" style="border:thin; border:1px solid black; float: right; margin-top:25px; margin-right:5px">
                Sign up
            </div>
            <div class="login" style="border:thin; border:1px solid black; float: right; margin-top:25px; margin-right:5px">
                login
            </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that I want to align the divs with class signup and login just above the div with class fbook. But I am unable to do so. I cannot figure out the problem. It would be great if someone could help.

Comment: Post you css OR create a Jsfiddle and update.

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/mDwEf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code and let me know

```
<div class="header" style="width:960px; height:120px; border:thin; border:1px solid black">
        <div class="logo" style="width:180px; height:100px; border:thin; border:1px solid black; float: left; margin-top:10px; margin-left:10px; margin-bottom:10px">
            LOGO
        </div>

        <div class="login_signup" style="float:right !important; width:100px;">
        <div class="signup" style="border:thin; border:1px solid black; float: right; margin-top:25px; margin-right:5px">
            Sign up
        </div>
        <div class="login" style="border:thin; border:1px solid black; float: right; margin-top:25px; margin-right:5px">
            login
        </div>



      <div class="fbook" style="float: right;margin-right: 40px; margin-top: 11px; text-align: center;">
            <img src="facebook.png"/>
        </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just put the div of the login and the signup above the fbook div

```
<div class="header" style="width:960px; height:120px; border:thin; border:1px solid black">
            <div class="logo" style="width:180px; height:100px; border:thin; border:1px solid black; float: left; margin-top:10px; margin-left:10px; margin-bottom:10px">
                LOGO
            </div>
           <div class="login" style="border:thin;float:right; border:1px solid black; ; margin-top:25px; margin-right:5px">
                login
            </div>
        <div class="signup" style="border:thin;float:right; border:1px solid black;  margin-top:25px; margin-right:5px">
                Sign up
            </div>
<br/>            
<div class="fbook" style="float: right; margin-top:50px; margin-right:5px">
                <img src="facebook.png"/>
            </div>


</div>
```